# A function cannot be included in its own domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

For what set theoretic reasons can a function not be included in its own domain?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by that? What exactly is a function to you? What does it mean for it to be included in its domain?

Comment: What about the function $\emptyset:\emptyset\to\emptyset$? We do have $\emptyset\subset\emptyset$. Do you mean that a function $f:E\to F$ cannot be an element of $E$?

Comment: Indeed, in Lambda Calculus, every element is a function with domain every element. (That doesn't help understand the set theoretic reasons for not allowing it, just pointing out that as a rule, it is possible to apply a function to itself...)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you are identifying lambda expressions with functions, and the two are quite different things. One *can* attach semantics to lambda calculus where the meaning of lambda expressions is a function, but in any case the way to do this properly is somewhat complicated. It is probable not the best example to bring out in this context! :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez well, it is the primary interpretation I know for Lambda calculus. Even the set theoretic definition of function is just a formality that we interpret as something like what we think of as a "function." As soon as I saw a question about "functions which are in their own domain," I thought of Lambda calculus.

Answer (score 8):

**Corrected:** A non-empty function **can** be a **subset** of its own domain. Let $x_0=0$, for each $n\in\omega$ let $x_{n+1}=\langle x_n,0\rangle$, and let $X=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$; then

$$f\triangleq\big\{\langle x_n,0\rangle:n\in\omega\big\}=\{x_{n+1}:n\in\omega\}\subseteq X=\operatorname{dom}f\;.$$

Comment: Also, the empty function is a counter example.

Comment: @Olivier: Since that’s immediately apparent, I’ve been tacitly assuming all along that $f\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Alright :). characters

Comment: OK. I'll delete

Comment: Very nice answer. Another variation would be to take $f$ defined on $V_\omega$ to be $f(x)=x\cup\{x\}$, then $f\subseteq V_\omega$ as well.

Answer (score 7):

One could use such a function to construct a set that violates the [Axiom of Regularity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)

**Note:** This answer assumes that "included" means "is an element of."

Comment: In this question included means $\in$, I suppose?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: That is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Presumably, if $f\in\mathrm{Dom}(f)$, that'd be the descending sequence $$f\ni \big(f,f(f)\big)=\lbrace f,\lbrace f,f(f)\rbrace\rbrace\ni f\ni \big(f,f(f)\big)=\lbrace f,\lbrace f,f(f)\rbrace\rbrace\ni f\ni\cdots$$